Chrome extension intercept and modify file upload
Is it possible to make a chrome extension that intercepts file uploads, convert it to the right file type, and the passed it on the file upload on the host website. Converting/compressing it I know can be done. What I don't know if it is possible for the extension to add something like a "floating upload" div or something, to "intercept" the file upload, and then pass it on to the original file upload element.
Use case 1: HEIC upload to website that only accepts jpg/png, etc -> convert to jpg automatically.
Use case 2: Gitlab video upload max size limit -> reduce the video size automatically.

You can intercept the getter for files property on HTMLInputElement.prototype in the MAIN world content script.
